# Getting last insert id with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy

```
import hashlib
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

from allsun.model import meta


t_user =  sa.Table("users",meta.metadata,autoload=True)

class Duplicat(Exception):
 pass
class LoginExistsException(Exception):
 pass
class EmailExistsException(Exception):
 pass

class User(object):
 """
 def __setattr__(self, key, value):
  if key=='password' :
   value=unicode(hashlib.sha512(value).hexdigset())
   object.__setattr__(self,key,value)
"""
 def loginExists(self):
  try:
   meta.Session.query(User).filter(User.login==self.login).one()
  except orm.exc.NoResultFound:
   pass
  else:
   raise LoginExistsException()

 def emailExists(self):
  try:
   meta.Session.query(User).filter(User.email==self.email).one()
  except orm.exc.NoResultFound:
   pass
  else:
   raise EmailExistsException()


 def save(self):
  meta.Session.begin()
  meta.Session.save(self)
  try:
   meta.Session.commit()
  except sa.exc.IntegrityError:
   raise Duplicat()
```

How can I get the last inserted id when I call:

```
user = User()
user.login = request.params['login']
user.password = hashlib.sha512(request.params['password']).hexdigest()
user.email = request.params['email']
user.save()
```

Answer (score 21):

You can access `user.id` (or whatever name you use for autoincremeted primary key field) after saving `user` object. SQLAlchemy automatically fills fields assigned by database.